# How do I use the default 'legalCommentPattern" with SonarQube

Tags: regex, sonarqube

I need a trailing comment in my code. Sonar keeps throwing [this error](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-139?search=comments). Unlike the public version, our Sonar says there is a way around this...

```
Parameters
    legalCommentPattern 
        Pattern for text of trailing comments that are allowed.

    Default Value:
        ^//\s*+[^\s]++$
```

This seems to suggest there is a way to add a comment to the EOL (which I need to do) but playing around in Regex pal I can't seem to figure it out.

How do I add a trailing comment that meets the `legalCommentPattern`. Or how do I change the value to allow for inline shorter comments.

Comment: The whole line should start with `//`, then have 0+ whitespaces, and then 1+ whitespace, e.g. `//  WORD`. If you want to have a comment anywhere in the string use `//.*$`

Comment: If that rule is not suitable for you project you can disable it by creating your own profile.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I don't think I control the profile. Can I use something like additional Properties? Or can I set this value to something?

Comment: You should read the [Quality Profile](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/quality-profiles/) part of the documentation. Looking [here](https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash/issues/157) I think it is not possible to set a profile based on a parameter. Also talk to your the quality officer.